# Отпразднуем завершение 2018го года Сезоном шляп!

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Мир полон удивительных традиций. Взять хотя бы [Ла Томати́на](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), [Апельсиновые сражения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Oranges), [Обезьяний пир](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_Buffet_Festival) или [Куперсхилдскую сырную гонку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0). Видя эти примеры неиссякаемого человеческого творчества, мы не смогли остаться в стороне и создали свой праздник — Сезон шляп!

[image: Image of Winter Bash 2018]

В этом году мы все вместе постараемся *связать* нашу любовью к шляпам в 7 раз подряд. И нам даже не потребуются реальные нити, чтобы проявить свое творчество...

С сегодняшнего дня (12 декабря 2018 года) по 1 января 2019 года [Сезон шляп](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) официально объявляется открытым! Вы можете заработать шляпы [выполняя задания](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) по участию в жизи сообществ Stack Exchange. Выполненные задания открывают вам доступ к специальным шляпам, которые вы можете «надеть» на ваше изображение в профиле участника, а затем «носить» на сайтах Stack Exchange. В этом году мы внесли изменения в набор шляп и даже добавили несколько предложенных вами! Триггеры для шляп также были обновлены... и да, есть несколько шляп, открыть которые каждый захочет лично.

После выполнения задания вы увидите изображение заработанной шляпы, которая появится вашей учетной записи:

[image: Image of hat icon in profile]

Нажмите на шляпу и вам откроется ящик со всеми вашими шляпами:

[image: Image of hat rack]

Выберите заработанную шляпу. Используйте инструменты изменения размера и вращения, чтобы шляпа подошла к вашему изображению профиля:

[image: Image of resize tool]

Вот и все! Теперь вы можете красоваться вашей коллекцией шляп. Хотите надевать новую шляпу каждый день? Как только вы заработали шляпу, решение только за вами! Однако, помните, что 2 января все шляпы будут отправлены на склад, где мы весь год будем чистить испачканные и ремонтировать те, которые порвались.

Желаем удачи и максимум удовольствия всем тем, кто присоединится к нашей ежегодной традиции!

Comment: Жалко, что шляпки заберут) Можно было дать возможность одну выбрать и на 1 год оставить)

Comment: А где страничка со шляпометрией? Посмотреть у кого сколько и какие шляпы?

Comment: @АндрейNOP На [страничке Сезона шляп](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) есть ссылка наверху справа «leaderboard». Если вы нажмете на нее, вы попадете на [страничку](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) с указанием лидеров.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev можно одеть шляпу, сфотографироваться и поменять аватарку на новое фото в шляпе ;-)

Comment: @Kromster, но шляпа может вылазить за аватарку ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Что я только что сделал :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А где же я в метрии, у меня же уже 2 шляпы :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А почему когда во второй раз пытаешься надеть шляпу, она уже не поворачивается и вообще контролы не появляются?

Comment: @VerNick, там галочку надо включить "показать инструменты"

Comment: Шикарно! Честно! Кстати, подскажите, а теперь можно будет "наехать" в комментах на несогласного(-ых), используя фразу: *задавлю, шляпа!* и не словить бан?))

Comment: опять не будут сохраняться( никакого стимула не остается больше помогать сообществу в этот период, в сравнении с обычным временем

Comment: Поставил аватарку в мессенджер. Жаль, нельзя сделать экспорт аватарки со шляпой.

Comment: Фотошоп вроде никто не отменял :)

Comment: Отпразднуем 2018 год качественным решением возникающих проблем!