# Почему не выдаётся шляпа Silencium?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, новогодние-шляпы

В [описании](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/silencium) знака:

> Silencium вопрос без ответов в течении недели

У меня 11 декабря [был задан вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918806/) и 12 декабря в 19:56 MSK [был задан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919239/) вопрос, оба до сих пор без ответов.

Допустим, я могу понять, что 11 декабря - это ещё не было объявлено о начале сезона шляп, но 12 декабря?

На русской мете [12 дек в 6:05](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8383/213987) было объявлено о начале сезона шляп, та же самая дата - 12тое декабря [указана](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/faq) в FAQ.

Неделя с12го числа прошла уже три дня как, так что дело не в том, что шляпа запаздывает, похоже, что есть какой-то баг. Либо -- вопросы должны быть заданы не после 12го, а после 13го.

Comment: Задал вопрос на MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320785/348096

Answer (score 5):

@Glorfindel [в ответе на mse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320786/348096) ссылается на то, что есть неявные [требования](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245122/348096) к получению знака:

> #### Неявные требования к качеству
>
> Чтобы избежать того, что люди начнут постить разную бессмыслицу/чушь
>   чтобы получить шляпу, большинство шляп которые требуют создания
>   контента, особенно вопросы и ответы, должны удолетворять требованиям,
>   которые могут быть не упомянуты в описании шляпы. Обычно это
>   подразумевает требование чтобы вопрос/ответ имели позитивный рейтинг
>   (т.е. как минимум один голос "за"

А рейтинг это вопроса у меня как раз ноль.